# CSS GRID and Bootstrap is it possible?

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, stylesheet

im trying to style the layout using the CSS GRID configuration, but its seems to not work together with bootstrap

my Fiddle -> http://jsfiddle.net/ucE9h/

what im trying to do is 1 row, 3 columns, #name in the first (large), #id2 in the middle(small) and the third column will span to the right

LIKE:

```
Name:                     Id:           ---------------------------------------
<Input hereeeeeeeeee>     <input heree> ---------------------------------------
```

Comment: I doubt whether it will work without bootstrap. [Compatibility results](http://caniuse.com/#search=grid-layout) says that no browsers except IE has supported css grid layout, and IE still requires `-ms-` prefix to work.

Comment: ok, i got it, strange that in this good thing just the IE works, anyway i will stay using bootstrap grid system

Comment: IE is leading standards related with text layout and publishing. Besides grid layout, there are also text alignment, paged layout etc. which are first implemented on IE.

Comment: so why everybody prefer other browser? its just because IE is SLOW?

Comment: That's complicated. IE has a bad reputation for outdated IE6,7,8. Some people are using old OSes which don't support newest IE. Some other browsers provided more friendly interface. Many other reasons.